# Duvida no uso aplicado de async/await com Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, async

Bom dia,

Mesmo lendo sobre os conceitos e usos do `async` e do `await` ainda estou tendo problemas na aplicação real deles.

Basicamente no meu `ngOnInit` faço a chamada para uma função:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticateUser();
  }
```

Função esta:

```
authenticateUser() {

    console.log("----Autenticando Usuário----");

    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    this.userPhoto = localStorage.getItem("userPhoto");

    this.currentUser = this.auth.getSession(this.token);

    this.attributions = this.currentUser.sessao.grupos;
    this.userEmail = this.currentUser.sessao.email;
    this.instalation = this.currentUser.instalacao;

   }
```

O problema é que o `currentUser` fica com o valor como `null` na sua execução, pois seu valor é setado sem receber o valor correto do `this.auth.getSession(this.token);`

Este `Auth` sendo construido de um serviço `RestApiService`

```
constructor(private auth: RestApiService) { }
```

Tendo dentro deste serviço o método `getSession()` que retorna um objeto `JSON` contendo informações de usuário retornadas pela `API`.

```
getSession(xtrToken) {
    xtrToken = "{\"token\":\"" + xtrToken.toString() + "\"}";
    this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/auth", xtrToken)
      .subscribe(function (resposta) {
        if (resposta != null) {
          localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(resposta));
          if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            var url = window.location.href;
            var value = url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf('?'));
            value = value.replace('@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]', '');
            var newUrl = value;
            window.history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
          }
          this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        }
      });
      return this.currentUser;
  }
```

Tentei colocar nessa função `getSession` como `async`, e na chamada dela algo deste tipo:

```
async authenticateUser() {

    console.log("----Autenticando Usuário----");

    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    this.userPhoto = localStorage.getItem("userPhoto");

    this.currentUser = await this.auth.getSession(this.token);

    this.attributions = this.currentUser.sessao.grupos;
    this.userEmail = this.currentUser.sessao.email;
    this.instalation = this.currentUser.instalacao;

   }
```

Porém não adiantou nada. Basicamente qual seria a forma correta de esperar o retorno da `API` antes de "setar" o valor de `this.currentUser` ?

Comment: Mathues, verifique sua API getSession, pois ela retorna "this.currentUser", sendo que o http.post é assíncrono, portanto antes mesmo de efetuar o set do valor quando o POST recebe a resposta, sua API já fez o retorno de um valor nulo.

O restante de sua implementação parece estar correto em relação ao uso do async/await.

Comment: a resposta da  API está correta, tanto que o localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(resposta));

Coloca a  resposta de forma correta

Comment: Porque não salvar em um let? This é o dono do objeto.

Comment: this.token retorna um valor correto, visto que eu passo ele como parametro para a api, e ela seta no localstorage o currentUser de forma correta.

Edit: Salvar o que no let examente?

Comment: Matheus poderia explicar melhor o que deseja fazer, onde se encontra a função **getSession(xtrToken)** e onde estaria a variável **`auth`**?

Comment: vou editar  com essas informações

Comment: Ja tentou colocar a função getSession com assíncrona? Pois não adianta a authenticateUser chamar a getSession como assíncrona sendo que ela não é.

Comment: sim, eu coloquei mas não adiantou